# Does Qt Resources system support having files just for testing?

Tags: qt, testing

I already used the Resources from Qt to add a couple of icons to the menu and works great, but now I was wondering if it would be possible to add a file that I need to use as a reference for testing purposes.

Therefore, I would like this file to be accesible **just** when I´m running the tests, not that it gets added to the binary of the application. Is there any way to set that differentiation?

I did not find something like that in Qt´s [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/resources.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it programmatically using QResource.

Or maybe writing on the .pro file (i have not tried it!! ) :

```
  Debug:RESOURCES += resources_only_debug_mode.qrc
```

more information here : [Qt .pro Docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmake-project-files.html)

Comment: I tried the second way and theoretically should work (it does differentiate between the Test and Release area of my .pro), but I don´t know why, it crashes at runtime when it tries to access the resource ("The program has unexpectedly finished."). That **only** happens when I´m running the tests, the regular program runs fine.

I checked also QResource, but I´m not able to make it work neither. findResource continues returning false:
bool findResource = QResource::registerResource("MyResources.qrc");

I tried too with the complete path ("/Users/MyName/MyProject/MyResources.qrc").

Comment: I found out my problem: In the main.cpp from the tests, I needed to call the application with the line QApplication app(argc, argv); Without it, it does not recognize the resources. Thanks for putting me on the right track!